# Globally defined variable not being found

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, global-variables, phantomjs

I have declared a global variable, `var linkArray=[]`, but it is not being picked up inside of a `phantomJS` function. The error message is: `phantom stdout: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: linkArray`. How can I make this be found? I've tried declaring it with `window.linkArray`, but since this is a headless application, I then get a different error, `ReferenceError: window is not defined`.

Thus, I need a way to make `var linkArray=[]` global.

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

var linkArray=[];

phantom.create(function (ph) {
    ph.createPage(function (page) {
        var main_file="file:///C:/whatever/index.html";
        page.open(main_file, function (status) {
            console.log("opened " + main_file +"\n",status+"\n");
            page.evaluate(function () { 
                for (var i=0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('a').length; i++) {
                    linkArray.push(document.getElementsByTagName('a')[i].href)
                }
                return linkArray; 
            }
            , function (result) {
                console.log(result)
                ph.exit();
            });

        });
    });
}, {
    dnodeOpts: {
        weak: false
    }        
});
```

Comment: I'm using node, so I use `npm` to install `phantom` and then declare `var phantom = require('phantom');`.

Comment: There is also https://github.com/alexscheelmeyer/node-phantom and many more. I see that both of them lead to the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhantomJS has a page context and outer context. The page context is sandboxed, so you need to explicitly pass the variable into it. It is passed by value. The [docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) say:

> Evaluates the given function in the context of the web page. The execution is sandboxed, the web page has no access to the phantom object and it can't probe its own setting.

But also note the *note*.

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will not work!**

To solve this, the outer variable has to be passed into the page context (`evaluate`) and returned

```
page.evaluate(function(linkArray) { 
    // page context, linkArray is a local variable now
    for (var i=0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('a').length; i++) {
        linkArray.push(document.getElementsByTagName('a')[i].href)
    }
    return linkArray;
}, function finished(result) {
    // outer context
    console.log(result)
    linkArray = result;
    ph.exit();
}, linkArray); // pass values for the page context as last parameters
```

Comment: Hmmm, it is recongnizing the linkArray, but for some reason returning an empty array if I run `console.log(linkArray)` after the last line (`}, linkArray);`)

Comment: That's because it is asynchronous and you broke out of the control flow (which is inside of the `finished` function).

Comment: PhantomJS leads to callback hell, especially those bridges. You may try another bridge like https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare. It has a highlevel API which is similar to CasperJS.